# iOS 7 present modal view inside UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My app is setup using a UINavigationController for all of the navigation. I am wanting to use a modal transition to present a specific view controller in the app. The thing is that I want to keep that new VC embedded inside of the navigation controller, but just that one view needs to use a modal animation rather than push.

How can I go about implementing this modal animation/transition on a single view controller within the UINavigationController?

Keep in mind that after this modal animation happens there will be buttons on that page that will proceed to work in line with a standard UINavigationController push animation.

Comment: forget that there is something like modal and do a presentModalView. that should work.

Comment: In iOS 7 presentModalViewController is deprecated and when I perform that method it takes that view out of the UINavigationController.

Comment: I mean [self.navigationController  presentViewController:yourViewController ... ]

Comment: modal view is always fullscreen, however you can change the presentationstyle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iOS7, this is possible using the new custom transitioning API. You can find more information here: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html

You create an animation controller (interactive or otherwise), and pass it in the appropriate method of the navigation bar delegate. In your animation controller, you perform the custom animation using `UIView` animation API. In your case, the animation should perform a slide from bottom into place for forward animation, and slide from place to bottom for reverse animation. If you support interactive animation, you can even control the curve of the animation in relation to the finger slide.

Comment: Do you have any experience using this personally? I'm curious because it would help me out if you gave me an idea of how to code it for this situation. Also this is not available for anything lower than iOS 7, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is a new API for iOS7. You can find ideas on how to implement and how the new transitioning API works in general here: https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary

For iOS6, I would say that a regular push animation may be enough, where you decidedly do not provide the full experience, like you do on iOS7. By the time you finish your app, it is likely iOS7 userbase would be in 85%+ (it is currently in its 80%\).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that! I am thinking about going an all iOS 7 route, but I'm not completely sure. It does make it more appealing when a majority of the user base is already on it.

Comment: It depends on how long you plan on developing and what your target audience is. There is obviously something appealing when you create an app that works on iOS6 as well. But you have to weight in the added testing time, working around missing API, bugs, etc. iOS7 itself contains bugs, so it can be quite a mouthful to handle both iOS6 and iOS7. Good luck!

Comment: While we're talking about it I would appreciate your opinion. The app I'm designing is geared towards College students. Do you think it'd be a good move to just go for iOS 7?

Comment: I think your target audience is among the most likely to upgrade. Especially, once a jailbreak is released for iOS7/7.1, the adoption rate would climb much higher. Students are also more likely to upgrade their devices more often, thus having devices capable of running the latest OS version.

Answer (score 4):

```
ITviewViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Replace the pseudo code with your view controller names.

Comment: This did work, but it takes that newly presented VC out of the UINavigationController. I guess what I'm really asking is how to present a view that is apart of my Navigation Controller with an animation that slides from the bottom of the screen to the top, similar to a standard modal transition. I need the UINavigationBar to persist after this animation so I can continue to push new pages on after.

Comment: UIModalPresentationFullScreen is default. This ain't gonna help. Its the same thing as doing  [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:Nil];

Comment: Help what? That is how you display a "modal", by setting the styles and presenting it.

Comment: @PeterFoti I think you should read the question first. His question is not how to display modal view but how to display modal view without covering navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

Modal view by default is full screen. You need to change presentation style to show navigationBar

EDIT : This only works for iPad. For iPhone you can use [MZformsheet](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController) or [Kentnguyen](https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNSemiModalViewController) to get semi modal behavior

```
MyModalViewController *targetController = [[[MyModalViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 

targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

targetController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; //transition shouldn't matter 

[self presentModalViewController:targetController animated:YES];


targetController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0,44/*navigation bar's height*/,height, width);//it's important to do this after 
// use full screen height and width here

targetController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

Comment: As was mentioned in the comments of the original question, `presentModalViewController` is deprecated.

Comment: @PeterFoti he can use alternative API but the logic is same.

Comment: He is developing for iPhone, these are iPad APIs. `modalPresentationStyle` is only taken into account (officially) when presenting a view controller modally on an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line not presentModelViewController

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work for you (self is UINavigationController):

```
- (void)verticalPushViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.9];
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [self pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
}

- (UIViewController *)verticalPopViewController
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.9];
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    return [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way.

To present

```
LaunchImageViewController *launchView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"launchImage"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:launchView.view];
```

To close. I calling this inside presented(LaunchImageViewController).

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```